# How kafka affects the work of Cryptogen and why?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Can someone explain to me the following sentence -

> While the cryptogen tool will create certificates for all five of
>   these orderers, **unless the Raft or Kafka ordering services are being
>   used**, only one of these orderers will be used in a Solo ordering
>   service implementation and be used to create the system channel and
>   mychannel.

It appears in the PDF version of the Hyperledger Fabric Documentation. 
What does the highlighted part mean?

Answer (score 0):

> While the cryptogen tool will create certificates for all five of
>   these orderers, unless the Raft or Kafka ordering services are being
>   used, only one of these orderers will be used in a Solo ordering
>   service implementation and be used to create the system channel and
>   mychannel.

This means cryptogen tool generates certificates for only one orderer if you use solo. As solo means single orderer in the ordering service

If you choose raft/kafka means cryptogen generates certificates for five orderers